# golang reflect create object is error

Tags: reflection, go

`less main.go` output:

```

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Id uint64 `json:"id"`
    No *string `json:"no"`
    Identity string `json:"identity"`
    Head url.URL `json:"head"`
}

func main() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(User{})
    u := reflect.New(t).Elem().Interface()
    fmt.Printf("u is %T, %v\n", u, u)
}
```

```

`go version` output:

`go version go1.5.2 darwin/amd64`

`go build main.go` correct

`./main` output:

`u is main.User, {0 <nil>  {  <nil>     }}`

what the matter?? why u object only third field? the User struct include four field!

In my really project, I find the created object's field's type is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure actually have 4 fields, notice the extra whitespaces that delimit the empty string field.

Try using the `%#v` to show the golang-syntax representation of your struct, that's much more easier to read (but can become quite crowded on big structures).